# What does "they heard you up all night again last night" mean?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

This phrase is from the film “The Unforgivable” 2021

Jenny is sick and her sister is talking with her

The sister says “**You know, they heard you up all night again last night. Gotta go back on your meds**”.

What does "**hear you up**" mean in this case?

Does it mean "**Jenny couldn't sleep well and got up several times in the middle of the night**" or may be "**Jenny had a broken sleep**" or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

This means somebody else (like the parents or neighbors or whoever "they" is referring to) were kept awake by Jenny's activity and noise. "Hear you up" literally means: to hear the noises another person makes because they are awake and moving around the room, closing drawers, etc. It also does imply that Jenny was awake and not sleeping well or at all, therefore if she were to get back on her meds, she would sleep again.

Comment: So, "**up**" here is an adjective meaning "**out of bed**" or "**awake**". So, it means "**I heard you out of bed**"?

Comment: Yeah! Pretty much exactly.